# Angular 2 Dropdown Menu first option not appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am using angular 2 and I created a drop down menu from options with the first option being a default option

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="pros" (ngModelChange)="onSelectProfessions($event)">
    <option value="0">Type of Healthpros</option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of professions" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.text}}</option>
</select>
```

However when I load the page, the first item is not displaying in the dropdown menu, its just empty, when I select a value, the value is selecting, see screenshots for details:

Before Selecting Value

[image]

After Selecting Value

[image]

How do I get the first value to appear so it says "Type of Healthpros" instead of just blank?

Here is what get rendered:

```
<select _ngcontent-c6="" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-reflect-model="">
    <option _ngcontent-c6="" value="0" ng-reflect-value="0">Type of Healthpros</option>
    <!--bindings={ "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object" }-->
        <option _ngcontent-c6="" value="1" ng-reflect-value="1">Health Technologist</option>
        <option _ngcontent-c6="" value="2" ng-reflect-value="2">Sport Medicine Physician</option>
        <option _ngcontent-c6="" value="3" ng-reflect-value="3">Medical Receptionist</option>
        <option _ngcontent-c6="" value="4" ng-reflect-value="4">Psychiatry</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please set this.pros = '0' by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initially your `pros` should equal to `"0"` because you have binded it using `ngModel`

```
this.pros = `0`
```